# North Bridge stuck in P1 state

Tags: power-management, gpu, amd, cpu-frequency

I have AMD E-350 processor stuck in NBP1 (north bridge P1) state in Linux (Debian 11) and doesn't transit into NBP0 state under CPU/GPU load. The problem doesn't take place in Windows.

Let's follow the diagram (all registers are in their default state with no custom modifications):

[image]

- Register `D18F6x90[NbPs1GnbSlowIgn]=0`, meaning  that "the GPU driver can specify the level of GPU activity that can cause an NB P-state transition". **(1) How can I check what does the driver report?** Even if set to `1`, the register (expectedly) doesn't change the behavior: NB still doesn't transit into NBP1 when CPU is in P0.
- Registers `D18F6x94[CpuPstateThrEn]=1` and `D18F6x94[CpuPstateThr]=1`, meaning that NB shall switch to NBP0, when CPU is in P0 state, irrespective of the GPU load. **(2) In reality, NB doesn't switch into NBP0, when CPU is in P0 state.**
- Register `D18F6x90[NbPsCtrlDis]=0`, meaning that CPU is expected to control NBP states autonomously.
- Register `D18F6x94[NbPs1NoTransOnDma]=0`, meaning that memory access do not affect NBP-state transitions.

My questions originate from the two highlighted statements above:

1. How can I check GPU activity reported by the GPU (radeon) driver and further troubleshoot lack of NBP transitions under a heavy GPU load?
2. How could Linux potentially prevent NBP transitions under CPU load (CPU P0 state), whereas they shall be autonomous from "SW"?